# Can't access localhost website

Tags: networking, apache2, localhost, owncloud-server

I have an owncloud server hosted on a virtual machine. I've been accessing it fine via My PC on the same network until randomly today this isn't working.

I just get the error "This site cannot be reached ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

I don't really know where to start looking, as i haven't changed any settings/files.

I can still access the URL from the web browser on the virtual server in which it is hosted, just not through any PC on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some update broke network settings.
Check connectivity with a ping.
If ping fails **and you are sure** that any firewall isn't blocking ping's protocol (ICMP), then check your virtual network configuration.

Please dont use localhost as destination address. Use vm ip instead.